# Render to Video FPS for Frame Animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I am trying to render a series of images to a timelapse.

- Frame Animation
- 1748 frames
- Each frame set to No Delay
- Render to Video, Frame Rate: 15 FPS

I've tried the Frame Rate setting of 15 FPS, 10 FPS, and 30 FPS.

30 FPS is very smooth, but far too fast.  I generally do my timelapses at 15 or 10 FPS.

The problem with the 15 and 10 FPS renderings, is that it is skipping frames.  So the difference between each frame is much larger.

**All three renderings are 58 seconds long**, and essentially play at the same speed.  The 15 FPS rendering uses only half the frames, skipping every other frame.  The 10 FPS rendering is using a third of the frames, skipping two frames between each.

Instead, what I want, would be for the 10 FPS rendering to be 174 seconds long, since that'd be how long the video was if it used all frames at 10 frames a second(1748frames/10 FPS= 174.8 seconds) .

I've also tried the timeline in video mode instead of frames(not sure what you call it exactly).  In this case you can set a Frames Per Second for the timeline, but you are also prompted at the rendering for the framerate.  The videos rendered like this have choppy parts that speed up and slow down.  I think there is a kind of picket fencing going on where the Codec's sampling rate occasionally double's frame.

**MakeAVI**
I tried a tool I've used in the past for this, and set it to output 15 FPS.  It basically takes a folder of images and outputs one image per frame. It gives me the results I want.  The video is the expected length and is very smooth, but the problem is it only supports a couple of very old codecs that don't ahve crisp image quality.

Comment: FRame skipping is very much a choice of codec and machine. NOt so much the software that made the images. After all the codec does the compression not the authoring tool.

Comment: @joojaa Absoultely not, I've never had a codec drop exactly 66% of frames at a given frame rate when the input and output FPS matched.  The fact that video length was the same in all three cases and the number of frames dropped in both the 10 and 15 GPS cases clearly indicates it is a rate mismatch with the input to the sampling.  This is what you would see if you provided a 30 FPS input to a codec and asked for a 15 FPS output.  I can use the same codec in VirtualDub and get correct results.  I ended up using VirtualDub instead.

Comment: Well it is possible that adobe does something cool on top but generally the codec does the work. So me compressing on any number of software on my computer and i get the exact same file because its calling the exact same code for compression (and i can see this by looking at process explorer that they all use the same DLL). But do chack that the codec settings are the same.

Comment: I am far from an expert on this topic, even with respect to our scope. However, it seems to me that [video.se] might at least be a more suitable place for this as they are certainly familiar with FPS issues. If you wish this question migrated, feel free to flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue with other tools if I provide a 30 FPS input source, and encode at 10 FPS or 15 FPS.

I ended up using VirtualDub instead since the FPS specified controls both the input and output FPS so that there wouldn't be a mismatch and got a smooth result at the expected video length of 174 seconds.

Comment: Yeap, Virtual Dub would be my first choice for this.